# YUI DataTable - how to avoid 'Stop running this script?' confirm message

Tags: javascript, yui-datatable

I am using YUI DataTable in my web application. While my DataTable is fetching the data if I close that and move on to other DataTable I keep getting the message 'Stop running this Script?' confirm message. I want to avoid this message and I want to stop the script from running as soon as I close the DataTable. Please give your suggestions. Please let me know if you need more info.
I am making a webservice call from JavaScript to populate DataTable. I suspect that is causing the prompt. I would require a way to stop script from executing webservice call

**Showing DataTable:**
    ShowDialog(DisambigPanel, ReturnElement)
    document.getElementById("DisambigList").focus();

```
DisambigDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(DisData[CurDisType].URL);
DisambigDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_XML;  
DisambigDataSource.responseSchema = {resultNode: DisData[CurDisType].Node, fields: DisData[CurDisType].Fields};         

var TableConfig =
{
    sortedBy: {key:DisData[CurDisType].SortKey, dir:"asc"},
    selectionMode: "single",
    initialRequest: BuildRequestString(),
    scrollable: true,        
    width: "940px",
    height: "340px",
    renderLoopSize: 20
}; 

YAHOO.widget.DataTable.MSG_LOADING = "<img src=\"/Images/Wait/DataGrid.gif\" alt=\"Loading animation\"/> Loading...";
YAHOO.widget.DataTable.MSG_EMPTY = "No results.";
DisambigTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("DisambigList", DisData[CurDisType].ColumnHeaders, DisambigDataSource, TableConfig);

YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener("DisambigList", "keydown"); 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("DisambigList","keydown",DisambigKeyDown);

DisambigTable.subscribe("initEvent",DisambigLoad);
DisambigTable.subscribe("cellDblclickEvent",DisambigSelect);
DisambigTable.subscribe("rowSelectEvent",DisambigSelectionChange)
```

function ShowDialog(dialog,returnFocus)
{
    OldFocus = returnFocus;
    VisibleDialog = dialog;

```
dialog.show()

var x = new YAHOO.util.KeyListener(document, { keys:27 }, { fn: HideDialog, scope:dialog, correctScope:true } ); 
x.enable();
dialog.cfg.queueProperty("keylisteners", x);
```

}

function HideDialog()
{
    // Hide the current dialog, if one is visible
    if (VisibleDialog)
    {
        // Hide the current dialog
        VisibleDialog.hide();
        VisibleDialog = null;
    }

```
if (OldFocus)
{
    OldFocus.focus();
    OldFocus = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I remember, that kind of a prompt is shown by FireFox if the script is taking too much time, or is in an infinite loop. Try checking whether it works in another browser apart from the one you're using...

Comment: I am getting this prompt on IE 7

Comment: yah - fix the problem, not the message!

Comment: @Naga - does it look like IE7 is issuing the message or is YUI issuing it?

Comment: It appears like a generic IE browser prompt.